# iText library's error code "The import com.itextpdf cannot be resolved" in Visual Studio Code. How to import library's in vscode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, itext

I would like to import the following libraries:

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.*;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;`
```

Unfortunately I get this error code:

[image]

I don't know what to do since it is my first time editing code in VS-Code. Eventually I even created the project not in a proper way.

Here is a picture of the project structure:

[image]

How to get rid of the error code?

I downloaded the library [here](https://github.com/itext/itext7). Is this the right library?

Comment: Out of curiosity, and to be able to improve the guidance for new users, what made you think you could ask a question in German here? Everything on the site is in English, as well as the [tour] and [ask] specifying posts need to be in English.

Comment: looks like you have a project structure issue, i advise to use some java project management tool like maven or gradle so the use of external libraries become simpler.

Comment: In your project you appear to have included iText 7 libraries as dependencies. Many of your imports, though, refer to iText 5 classes which do not exist is iText 7 anymore (at least not in the same package). Thus, you have to make your code and your referenced libraries match.

Answer (score 0):

vscode uses the currently opened folder as the workspace, so first you need to use vscode to open your project folder, and then the java extension will automatically recognize the java project and display it in the **JAVA PROJECTS** panel.

Click `Referenced Libraries` under the project's name to see the added reference, and click the plus sign on the right to add a reference.

[image]

See [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_dependency-management) for more information.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I did what you described to do. However, if I click on  my library folder to add this as a referenced library, it doesn't work. Nothing happens. 

the name of the folder is "itext7-develop" I downloaded it here: https://github.com/itext/itext7

Is this the right folder to add?

Comment: Or might it be a better way for a beginner just like me to integrate the library with a pom which I can download here: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.itextpdf%20AND%20a:itext7-core&core=gav ? 

If that is true, what do I need to set up so it will work?

Comment: You should add the `.jar` file. If you use maven, you only need to make corresponding modifications in the *pom.xml*. If it is a local `.jar` package, then you need to install it to the local warehouse before modifying the *pom.xml*.